# Matching exactly 10 digits in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've tried other questions on SO but they don't seem to provide a solution to my problem:

I have the following simplified Validate function

```
function Validate() {
    var pattern = new RegExp("([^\d])\d{10}([^\d])");

    if (pattern.test(document.getElementById('PersonIdentifier').value)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've tested to see if the value is retrieved properly which it is. But it doesn't match exactly 10 digits. I don't want any more or less. **only** accept 10 digits otherwise return false.

I can't get it to work. Have tried to tweak the pattern in several ways, but can't get it right. Maybe the problem is elsewhere?

I've had success with the following in C#:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)")
```

Examples of what is acceptable:

> 0123456789
>   ,1478589654
>   ,1425366989

Not acceptable:

> a123456789
>   ,123456789a
>   ,a12345678a

Comment: Bob's your uncle `^[0-9]{10}$`. `^` means begin of string and `$` means end of string.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. Can you recommend a good link/text/tutorial on regular expressions? I seem to have just jumped into it and it gets quite messy sometimes.

Comment: BTW, quoted characters passed to the RegExp constructor must be double quoted: `new RegExp('^\\d{10}$')` should do the trick. A literal is simpler: `/^\d{10}$/`.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ as well as [Stack Overflow: What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can try with `test()` function that returns `true/false`

```
var str='0123456789';
console.log(/^\d{10}$/.test(str));
```

OR with `String#match()` function that returns `null` if not matched

```
var str='0123456789';
console.log(str.match(/^\d{10}$/));
```

**Note:** Just use `^` and `$` to match whole string.

Answer (score 15):

You can use this:

```
var pattern = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can try this :

```
var str = "0123456789";
var pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9]{10}$");
pattern.test(str);
```